# Server Error with Python code for Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, internal-server-error

I have been trying to deploy code onto GAE but I keep getting 500 server error when trying.

Using the Pycharm environment I do not see errors in the code. Can someone help me with what is causing the issue? I have also tried to use the Postman plugin to get responses with GET and POST but unable to do so due to 500 Internal Server Error.
Thanks for the time and help.

The error in the AppEngine Logs.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 269, in _LoadHandler
    raise ImportError('%s has no attribute %s' % (handler, name))
ImportError: <module 'main' from '/base/data/home/apps/s~newstartapptest/1.367182586650515795/main.py'> has no attribute app
```

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: you could try help(self.request) to get some more info

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~newstartapptest/1.367182297362347420/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext import webapp2
ImportError: cannot import name webapp2

Comment: I will upload it onto the main post, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app.yaml`, assuming the code you show above is in `main.py`, you're probably using

```
script: main.app
```

But the global you're using to hold the `WSGIApplication` is named `application`, not `app`. Rename the variable.

Comment: Hello, I have made the changes and I think it's fixed the file. Though whenever I try localhost now I get a download file called 'download'. Would this be because of a lack of a html file with the python? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try using a valid Content-Type (e.g., `text/html` instead of `main/html`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The python file looks fine now!

Answer (score 0):

You either have to:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
```

Or,

```
import webapp2
```

Comment: Hello, by using from google.appengine.ext import webapp. It has resolved part of error. Thank you.

Comment: Can you use the `import webapp2` statement? That would be the best to use, since you are referring to `webapp2.RequestHandler`s in your code.

Comment: I will give that a go too as I had to change my RequestHandlers to just webapp.